# Unable to call static method of class received as an upper-bounded ("extends") generic in Java 6?

Tags: java, generics, static

I have problem with templates and static methods a in Java (version 6), which may be divided into two sub-problems:

First, I need to find a way how I can return a templated `Iterable` (out of static context) that creates new instances of some sub class (e.g., B) of an abstract class (e.g., A) in every iteration.  (Background: I need to translate one object (e.g., a String) from an iterable into another object).  I found a way with templates/generics:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Test {

    public static <T extends A> Iterable<T> getIterable(final Iterator<String> i) {

        return new Iterable<T>() {

            public Iterator<T> iterator() {

                return new Iterator<T>() {

                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return i.hasNext();
                    }

                    public T next() {
                        try {
                            /* this is where things go wrong:        *
                             * T is considered as class A and not B  */
                            return T.factory(i.next());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    public void remove() {
                        i.remove();
                    }        
                };

            }

       };

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashSet<String> st = new HashSet<String>();
        st.add("x1");

        Iterable<B> bi = getIterable(st.iterator());
        for (B b : bi)
        {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, I have defined the following class hierarchy:

```
/* super class */
abstract class A
{
    public static <T extends A> T factory(String c)
    {
         /* returns nothing, should never be called */
         return null;
    }
}

/* child class */
class B extends A
{
    String s;
    public B (String s) { this.s = s; }

    public static B factory(String s)
    {
        return new B(s);
    }
}
```

The overall way seems to work (in principle).  However, the static method `factory` called will be always the one in the super class A, even though the template `T` is of type B.

I am looking for any ideas/suggestions of how to call the factory of the sub class, i.e., of the class that comes with the template `<T>` (e.g., B).  Any help is highly appreciated!

(Note: I found that in Java 7, one could use interfaces and inherit/override static methods, but I am bound to Java 6 ...)

Comment: Removing `[templates]` tag as Java doesn't have templates.

Answer (score 3):

The Java keyword `static` has a meaning to the compiler: It allows the compiler to *statically* bind a method call to a method *at compile time*. Therefore the compiler writes a call to the method `A.factory(String)` into the produced byte code when compiling the line `return T.factory(i.next()).`

You obviously wanted to override the factory method in B to have a dynamic behavior when running the program. For that behavior, you must remove the `static` keyword.